# How quickly does the colon absorb water in rectal hydration?

Tags: colon

According to the following article, "infusion at rates of up to 250 - 400 mL/h have been shown to be well tolerated"

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5226138/

Does this mean the colon absorbs 250-400 ml of water every hour? And is it being continuously administered by a drip? Or is the fluid administered in a single dose and then left to be absorbed before more is added? I'm not a medical student, so a lot of the terms in the article don't make sense to me.

Comment: The video included in the article you linked to answers your question.